# Sequelize filter based on JOIN results

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have a table `orders` which have a belongs to many relationship to `categories`.
i.e. an order can have the categories `food`, `fruit`, `banana` all at the same time.

`Order.belongsToMany(models.category, { through: 'orderCategory', as: 'categories' });`

I want to make a query to get all orders that have at least one of the given categories.
For example, give me all orders that have the `food` category. This would be simple if I'm happy with getting the order including only the food category in the JOIN. But I want to include all categories even if only one of them matches. So essentially I need to filter on values based on the left outer join result.

My query right now:

```
order.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: models.category,
      as: 'categories',
      where: {
        id: 'a437ffab-5085-4fd7-b193-23dfb299aa39',
      },
      // required: false,
    },
  ],
})
```

I've also tried to put the where statement on the parent.

`{ '$categories.id$': 'a437ffab-5085-4fd7-b193-23dfb299aa39' }`
But I guess it's essentially the same.

One idea is to do the filtering after the fetch instead, but then I wouldn't be able to do proper limit and offset.

Edit:
From a suggestion from a comment, I have written the raw SQL for this, which might make it easier to then try to translate it to Sequelize.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    orders
    JOIN order_categories ON order_categories.order_id = orders.id
WHERE
    orders.id in(
        SELECT
            order_id FROM order_categories
        WHERE
            order_categories.category_id = 'a437ffab-5085-4fd7-b193-23dfb299aa39')
```

I'm not sure if this is the most effective way, but it works.
Now the question is how to do this with Sequelize.

Comment: Do you have a raw query for it? I think primary goal should be to draft a raw query with the expected output first and then try to implement it in sequelize.

Comment: Thank you thats a good suggestion. I've added the raw SQL now. @cupid22

Comment: that's a literal where query, also do this query really work for you as it might raise that subquery has to return only one record

Comment: Yes this query works perfectly. The subquery will not only return one record, but rather the id's of all orders that matches the given category_id. And since I'm then using a IN, I will get exactly what I want: The order details and also ALL categories for those orders that matches the inner query criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
let we have an order_id with name of order_id. then we can retrive data using this code 

order.findAll({
     where:{id:order_id},
  include: [
    {
      model: models.category,
      as: 'categories',
      where: {
        id: 'a437ffab-5085-4fd7-b193-23dfb299aa39',

      },
      // required: false,
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I follow what you mean by this suggestion. This would only filter on a certain order id, that is not what I want. Check the SQL above for an example of what the expected outcome should be.